# Display Progress on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to make a progress running on Navigation Drawer like this:

[image]

I have created a navigation drawer successfully, but don't know how to make a progress bar like that. Is it possible ? I'm really appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have created a navigation drawer successfully you must have a layout. Just put a `ProgressBar` in the layout where your `ListView` is (`DrawerLayout`'s 2nd child). You can initialize and use it as usual after `setContentView` via `findViewById`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="start"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/myList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/myProgress"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:progress="40"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

If you want it to scroll you'll have to create an adapter where one of the itemTypes is that `ProgressBar`.

In case you were just wondering how to make a horizontal progress bar: [read this](http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/)